# Growth of the constants from the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, growth-rate

The Stone Weierstrass theorem for $C([0,1])$ claims that for any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a polynomial $p_{n,f}(x)=\sum_ia_{f,n,i}x^i$ such that $\left\|f-p_{n,f}\right\|_\infty<\frac{1}{n}$. I would like to know results about bounds of $\sum_i|a_{f,n,i}|$ in terms of $f$ and $n$.

To be more specific, are there known bounds $U(N,L,n)$ such that for any $L$-Lipschitz function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\|f\|_\infty<N$ we can find a polynomial $p_{f,n}(x)$ as above with $\sum_i|a_{f,n,i}|<U(N,L,n)$?

My motivation to ask is this MO [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/442509/172802), maybe it has a positive answer if the bounds $U(N,L,n)$ exist and don't grow very fast.

Comment: There is constructive proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem due S. N. Bernstein. Keyword: Bernstein polynomials. It gives a bound on coefficients and the degree in terms of the modulus of continuity.

Comment: Thanks! After searching "Bernstein polynomials" I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3889525/807670) which contains a few references

Comment: Basically you are asking how to bound the coefficient of a polynomial with its sup-norm. A way is to use iteratively Markoff  inequality saying that $\|P'\|_\infty \leq 2n^2 \|P\|_\infty$ if $n$ is the degree.